# Pyspark, how to locally define type treatments

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

This post is more for getting recommendations than getting a solution.

Say that I'm using these four types within my pyspark environment: `str`, `dbl`, `int`, `date`.
The banking sector in my country is very archaic, and I end up sending data in strange formats like fixed width.
The business partners give very interesting specifications on how to send the data text files.
Of course this brings up many philosophical questions, but for now I'll stay in the present.

One such example is:
`dbl(5,2)` (width, prec) has `N/A`'s as `0` with no decimal marker.
Thus `14.2 -> 01420`.

Or `date` has `1900-01-01` as its `N/A` value and is sent via `DDMMYYYY`.

One intermediate approach before generating reports is to create a local type handler:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T, Column

class TypeHandler(): 
    nas = dict(int=0, dbl=0, str='', date=date(1900, 1, 1))
    sparks = dict(int=T.IntegerType, dbl=T.DecimalType, 
        str=T.StringType, date=T.DateType)
    c_formats = dict(int='%0{}d', dbl='%0{}.{}f', 
        str='%-{}.{}s', date='%8.8d')


    def __init__(self, type_key): 
        self.type = type_key

        self.NA = nas[type_key]
        self.spark = sparks[type_key]
        self.c_format = c_formats[type_key]


    def column_fix_width(self, col:Column, *args): 
        width = args[0]
        c_format = self.c_format 

        if   self.type == 'str': 
            y_format = c_format.format(width)
            c_column = F.format_string(y_format, col)

        elif self.type == 'dbl': 
            prec = args[1]
            y_format = c_format.format(width, prec)
            y_column = F.format_string(y_format, col)
            c_column = F.regexp_replace(y_column, '[\.,]', '')
        
        elif self.type == 'int':
            x_format = c_format.format(width)
            c_column = F.format_string(x_format, col)

        elif self.type == 'date': 
            c_column = (F.when(col.isNull(), F.lit(self.NA))
                .otherwise(F.date_format(col, 'ddMMyyyy')))

        s_format = '%{}.{}s'.format(width, width)
        return F.format(s_format, c_column)
```

So given a table of attributes with its corresponding type and specifications, I found this TypeHandler good enough to iterate and create the corresponding Spark objects.

The question is, what are your thoughts on creating such TypeHandlers?

I have looked in Spark and found nothing similar besides the `T.IntegerType()` constructor and its cousins.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: i like that this approach standardizes the formats into one class easily readable and reusable, but you could probably accomplish the same thing with some conditional statements where you format columns based on their type which might be more performant

Comment: Thank you for your response.  
While I did start with some conditional statements, I felt them a bit inadequate to handle all the cases.  
After writing my post I found this article on Factory Design, which seems close to what I want to do, but still not so digestable or straightforward.  
https://realpython.com/factory-method-python/

Comment: It's quite good, but to give you something: use f-strings, maybe refactoring `column_fix_width` to handle different data types in different methods, methods for error handling, more documentation, ...